# Error after upgrading Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

After upgrading Magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 (or 2.4.5), I cannot run any Magento CLI command. For example, setup upgrade command:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

generates the errors:

> Interface "Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable" not found#0
> /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
> #1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
> #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
> #3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38):
> class_exists()
> #4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(157):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has()
> #5 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(180):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception()
> #6 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(213):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins()
> #7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(190):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->generateIntercepted()
> #8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(122):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->initializeUncompiled()
> #9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct()
> #10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
> #11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> #12 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(84):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
> #13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(191):
> Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager()
> #14 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create()
> #15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(127): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct()
> #16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create()
> #17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(85): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->initObjectManager()
> #18 /var/www/magento2/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
> #19 {main}

I tried by removing all cache's, generated codes etc, but I receive always this error. How can I fix it?

I also receive the below error:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> Class 'Zend\Mime\Mime' not found#0
> /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php(366):
> ReflectionParameter->getDefaultValue()
> #1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php(396):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract->extractParameterDefaultValue()
> #2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\EntityAbstract->_getMethodParameterInfo()
> #3 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Code/Generator/Interceptor.php(103):
> array_map()
> #4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Code/Generator/Interceptor.php(76):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\Generator\Interceptor->_getMethodInfo
> ....
> #65 /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
> #66 /var/www/magento2/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
> #67 {main}

Answer (score 1):

To fix JsonSerializable error, you can implement

```
\JsonSerializable
```

instead of

```
Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Please check the php version first i.e.

```
php -m
```

Are you using PHP 8? If not, first, you need to upgrade to PHP 8.

2: Please remove the vendor folder and backup for the safer side. And then run the command: `composer install.`

3: Install the package again of Zend Framework.

4: Please confirm if **mcrypt extension** is enabled in PHP.

5: Try running the composer update followed by composer install, this should place JsonSerializable in vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/JsonSerializable.php.

Thanks